# excel not reading some data

Tags: python, excel, csv

I created a csv file in Python with 150 columns, which should have values 0, 1 or 2 inside each column. I open excel -> data -> get data -> from Text -> i choose comma as delimiter etc. The problem is that only the first column is filled with the desired values correctly, the other 149 columns are empty. However, when I open that file in PyCharm, where I wrote the code, it looks good, so each column is filled properly.

I saved the data using

```
allData.to_csv('allData.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the delimiter explicitly to a comma when saving the CSV file using the sep parameter in the to_csv function. Here's an example code:

```
import pandas as pd
# Create a sample DataFrame with 150 columns containing 0, 1, or 2
data = pd.DataFrame({'col_' + str(i): [0, 1, 2] for i in range(150)})
# Save the data to a CSV file with comma as delimiter
data.to_csv('allData.csv', index=False, sep=',')
```